# How to post public status updates to facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have a method for posting status updates to facebook from within my app as below.
Everything works but I whould like to be able to change the privacy setting of the status since it always posts only to my friends now and I would like to have it post to the public.

How should I do this or is there some limitation with that in the API?

```
private void postToFacebook(String message)
    {
        if(Session.getActiveSession().isOpened())
        {
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest((Activity) this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
            Session.getActiveSession().requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionRequest);
            Request request = Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), message, new Callback()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response)
                {
                    FacebookRequestError fer = response.getError();
                    if(fer != null)
                    {
                        Log.d("FBSEND", fer.getErrorMessage());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Posted Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the javadoc for the library you are using?

Comment: erm... well it's the official facebook SDK so yea I guess right?..
The only library imported is the Facebook SDK and then the Android Support Library v4.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/ ?

Comment: if you ask if I've read there to solve my problem then yes, but I did not find an answer there that made me understand how to do this

Comment: No I was asking if this was the API you were using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things to consider here.

First of all, most users do not like to post publicly, and if your app asks for public permissions, they are more likely to deny your permission request.

Secondly, the user can change the privacy that your app posts to at any time (without the app knowing), so even if you request public permissions, it can be anything else in the future (and it will be out of your control).

Lastly, you can only ask for the privacy ceiling once, when you ask for the publish permissions. In your NewPermissionsRequest, you can call setDefaultAudience, something like:

```
newPermissionRequest.setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.EVERYONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a public post you should send privacy parameter along with the request.

```
Request req = new Request();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("privacy","{'value':'EVERYONE'}");
req.setParameters(b);
req.newStatusUpdateRequest(...
```

Hope this would work. Ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/privacy-parameter/

P.S: I haven't tried this code.